# With `docker run`, can I remove the container by default?

Tags: docker, shell, command-line

I frequently forget to use `--rm` and end up with multiple stopped containers. These tend to fill up my filesystem and prevent docker pruning from removing unused images.

Ideally, I'd be able to configure docker or my shell to use the `--rm` option whenever I run `docker run` without `-d`.

Is there a way to remove a docker container after it's running by default, if not detached? If this is a bad idea, why?

Comment: You can create an alias which supplied the option if it's not already present but it will need to be rather involved to correctly pass through other options to `docker run` and do nothing for other `docker` subcommands.